# как одним запросом вычислить наименьшую дату в двух таблицах

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такие запросы 
select min(processed_date) from batch;
select min(processed_date) from retail_transaction_cycle;
Нужно их объединить и получить меньшую дату из двух запросов одним запросом

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT .. FROM ... UNION SELECT ... FROM ...);` такая конструкция не прокатит?

Comment: ``SELECT LEAST(q1.min, q2.min) FROM (SELECT MIN(..) AS `min` FROM .. ) AS q1,  (SELECT MIN(..) AS `min` FROM .. ) AS q2)``